# ASP.NET download file from server

Tags: asp.net, iis, infragistics

I'd  like to download a file from server to the client.
Neither of the solutions I found across internet works, they all write the file to the server, but never pops the download window on the client's browser.
I don't know whether it is a ASP.NET issue or IIS.

This is my code:

```
Workbook wb = getExcel();
string pathDownload = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/DOCUMENTS/temp/Excel.xls");

BIFF8Writer.WriteWorkbookToFile(wb, pathDownload);
byte[] fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathDownload);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();

HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Excel.xls");
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(fileContent);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `WriteWorkbookToFile` already writes the file in question to the file system, it is preferable to use it straight from there rather than load it into memory and then do a BinaryWrite.

remove the line:

```
byte[] fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathDownload);
```

and then replace the line:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(fileContent);
```

with:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(pathDownload);
```

Comment: It downloads the file on the server side, not to the client. That's why I thought it might be a IIS configuration or something. Any idea? thanks.

Comment: @JonyCoboMira - I don't think I understand `downloads the file on the server side` your asp.net code on the server is creating the file and then pushes it down to the client. It's that what you want?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I want but neither mine nor your code do it. I mean, the code creates a copy in the server machine but never on the client. The user clicks on a button in my web page to download a file, that file is created on my server, but the user never gets the file